# How to append the text to text file in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to append the text to a text file in blackberry ,how can i do it

Comment: What do you mean by this? You want to add some kind of String to a text file and save it on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this code. This basically writes log to a file in SD Card. You can customize the way you want.  Enjoy.

```
static String pFilePath = "SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/Log.txt";

    public static void writeLog(String data) {
        FileConnection fc = null;
        OutputStream lStream = null;
        Date d = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = new String();
        if (pFilePath != null) {
            try {
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///" + pFilePath,
                Connector.READ_WRITE);
            if (null == fc || fc.exists() == false) {
                fc.create();
            }
            lStream = fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize());
            c.setTime(d);

            time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND)            + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
            data = "\n" + time + "("
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTimeMillies)
                + " ms)" + " -- " + data;
            currentTimeMillies = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lStream.write(data.getBytes());

            } catch (Exception ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            if (lStream != null) {
                try {
                lStream.close();
                lStream = null;
                } catch (Exception ioex) {
                }
            }
            if (fc != null) {
                try {
                fc.close();
                fc = null;
                } catch (Exception ioex) {
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
```